# appcache not working any more - not loading offline

Tags: html5-appcache

I have tested my website thoroughly offline (just using localhost). And I have never had a problem with appcache - such that I could load my website, disconnect my phone from the wi-fi, reload the website and I could still view it.

Now I have put my website online (ie. http://subdomain.example.com) - the code is exactly the same - and I try the same thing.

It will just not work. Chrome on my phone says wi-fi and mobile are unavailable and the page can't be loaded.

I just don't understand. Is there anything that anyone can think of that is different about working locally to working on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem in the future, check your paths in .appcache

In turned out that the change between local and online (ie. 10.0.0.10/myapp/Symfony/mobile vs subdomain.example.com) meant that the `/` I had in the first line of my manifest was pointing to different locations on both local and online.